# Finding a domain name ending with worldpay.com or rbsworldpay.com from Dns.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one please help me to find domain name ending with worldpay.com or rbsworldpay.com from

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(givenip);

var hostName = entry.HostName.ToLower();
```

Now i want to make sure hostName ends only with worldpay.com or rbsworldpay.com and things else i want to throw an exception.

Can any one please help.

Even regular expression check should do?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with using string.EndsWith? What have you tried and why has it not worked?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
if(hostName.EndsWith("worldpay.com")||hostName.EndsWith("rbsworldpay.com")
{
   throw new Exception("wrong host");
}
```

It will throw new Exception when `hostName` ends with `worldpay.com` or `rbsworldpay.com`

Comment: I am pretty sure it will also find domain names ending with xxxworldpay.com or spoofrbsworldpay.com

Comment: @user2717619 It will, but isn't it a desired effect? "to find domain name ending with worldpay.com or rbsworldpay.com"